# Dynamic time interval to call a function node.js

Tags: node.js, date, cron, setinterval, scheduler

I have divided a day on 6 parts and each part of a day has its own interval. My function must run in this intervals.
for example 12:00pm - 15:00pm interval is 10 min, so function must be called every 10 min, but 15:00pm - 20:00pm interval is 2 min so from 15:01pm interval must be changed from 10min to 2min.

Need a suggestion how to build this kind of timer.
I can get intervals from mongoDB or local json file.
I guess I have to check what time is it and get an interval (from mongoDB or json file) for that time, then pass it to `setInterval()` or [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job scheduler.
Tryed this way but every time im passing new interval last intervals are still working: If interval is 2 min and im changing it to 5 min, function is called twice: every 2 min and every 5 min in both `setInterval()` and [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

```
const test = (min) => {
    console.log(min);
    var intervale = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('firing', min, new Date());
    }, min);
}

const test = (min) => {
    cron.schedule(`0 */${min} * * * *`, () => {
        console.log('firing cron', new Date())
    });
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this? This uses the EventEmitter model and fires an event based on the custom Interval.

```
const eventemitter_cls = require("events").EventEmitter;
let eventemitter = new eventemitter_cls();

intervalName = "randomintervals"

let sumOfTwoNumbers = () => {
    console.log(`hello world ${(new Date()).getMinutes()} ${(new Date()).getSeconds()}` );
    // After you are done with your function, again you need to emit the event based on the time interval
    setTimeout(() => {
        eventemitter.emit(intervalName)
    }, getTimeInterval());

}

let getTimeInterval = () => {
    let currentTime = new Date();
    // put your complicated interval schedule here
    if(currentTime.getHours() >= 10 && currentTime.getHours() < 11){
        return 5000;
    }
    else if (currentTime.getHours() > 12 && currentTime.getHours() < 15) {
        return 2000;
    }
    else{
        return 1000;
    }
}

// give your function name here. the function will be called whenever someone emits intervalName
eventemitter.on(intervalName, sumOfTwoNumbers);
eventemitter.emit(intervalName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think It's still firing because there is no `clearInterval` telling it to stop.